# How to combine ‘float’ and ‘longtable’ packages functionality

Tags: tables, floats, longtable

I want to use exact placement for my table. As I [read on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673942/latex-table-positioning) it can be done with [H] option for table environment provided by ‘float’ package. But this doesn't seem to work with longtable which I have to use due to the fact that my table is really long.

What I tried so far

```
% Preamble
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{longtable} % as \restylefloat{table} doesn't take effect

…

% Long table
\begin{longtable}[H]{| c | c | c | c |}
\hline
1        & 5 & 6 & 7  \\ \hline
1        & 5 & 6 & 7  \\ \hline
1        & 5 & 6 & 7  \\ \hline
% and so on, many rows
\end{longtable}
```

This gives me a bunch of errors like

```
Misplaced \noalign. [\hline]
Misplaced alignment tab character &. [1          &]
```

Maybe there are some other ways to get desired behaviour of longtable?

**EDIT**: I add the screenshot of exact problem with longtable placement. In short: it is placed before the paragraph, while I wrote it after.
[image: longtable problem]

Comment: tables will never move unless you ask them to move by surrounding them with `begin{table}` which makes them float. `longtable` never moves at all. So what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: please always make your code sections complete documents so people can reproduce the error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I use \paragraph{Title} _then_ longtable. The table is placed _before_ the paragraph title and that's not what I expect.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I can't see an incorrect markup so I added an image of what is going on.

Comment: Please always make a _complete_ document that demonstrates the problem, don't post incomplete fragments or images of code. `\paragraph` is an _inline_ heading, the heading is added to the first line of the following paragraph so you may need to use `\mbox{}` after the heading, but why are you using an inline heading there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As clarified in comments the problem is unrelated to floating environments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}


\begin{document}

\paragraph{zz}

\begin{longtable}{| c | c | c | c |}
\hline
1        & 5 & 6 & 7  \\ \hline
1        & 5 & 6 & 7  \\ \hline
1        & 5 & 6 & 7  \\ \hline
% and so on, many rows
\end{longtable}

aa

\end{document}
```

`\paragraph` is an *inline* heading (designed to be used after `\subsubsection`) the heading is held back and added to the first line of the following paragraph.

`longtable` does not start a paragraph so the heading gets added to `aa`.

To fix this add an empty paragraph

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}


\begin{document}

\paragraph{zz}
\mbox{}%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{longtable}{| c | c | c | c |}
\hline
1        & 5 & 6 & 7  \\ \hline
1        & 5 & 6 & 7  \\ \hline
1        & 5 & 6 & 7  \\ \hline
% and so on, many rows
\end{longtable}

aa

\end{document}
```

But are you sure you want an inline rather than a display heading in this context?

Comment: Then I've got the problem pictured on a screenshot that I added to my post.

Comment: @ArtemPelenitsyn that is why _every_ question should have a _complete_ document that _demonstrates the problem_ (which is unrelated to floats in this case).

Comment: @ArtemPelenitsyn I edited the answer

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! This “empty mbox”-weird things I encountered them a couple of times… Never understand why tables don't start paragraph (unless you use table environment and got floating which is the whole another story).

Comment: I need inline variant for the sake of consistensy. I have a text, where some paragraphs must have numbers and optional titles, both inline. But some paragraphs, as you see, have number, title and display table right after it.